# using amCharts without directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amcharts

So I am trying to use amCharts in my angular application, I tried using it as a directive, but it never worked, then I decided to use it as it is documented in its website. However, that did not work either.

Here s what I put in my controller:

```
var chartData = [{
        "country": "USA",
        "visits": 4252
    }, {
        "country": "China",
        "visits": 1882
    }, {
        "country": "Japan",
        "visits": 1809
    }, {
        "country": "Germany",
        "visits": 1322
    }, {
        "country": "UK",
        "visits": 1122
    }, {
        "country": "France",
        "visits": 1114
    }, {
        "country": "India",
        "visits": 984
    }, {
        "country": "Spain",
        "visits": 711
    }, {
        "country": "Netherlands",
        "visits": 665
    }, {
        "country": "Russia",
        "visits": 580
    }, {
        "country": "South Korea",
        "visits": 443
    }, {
        "country": "Canada",
        "visits": 441
    }, {
        "country": "Brazil",
        "visits": 395
    }, {
        "country": "Italy",
        "visits": 386
    }, {
        "country": "Australia",
        "visits": 384
    }, {
        "country": "Taiwan",
        "visits": 338
    }, {
        "country": "Poland",
        "visits": 328
    }];




    AmCharts.ready(function() {
        // chart code will go here
        var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
        chart.dataProvider = chartData;
        chart.categoryField = "country";

        var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
        graph.valueField = "visits";
        graph.type = "column";
        chart.addGraph(graph);

        chart.write('chartdiv');

    });
```

And here is what put in my html file

```
<div ng-controller="ReportsController as reportCtrl">


<h2>Reports</h2>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 640px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

seems like something is wrong/missing, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AmCharts.ready()` occurs when the document's onload event occurs. Putting the code in the AngularJS controlled means that it is executed **after** this event has already occurred, meaning the code never gets executed.

You have two options here:

1) Remove your code out of the `amCharts.ready()` wrapper:

```
// chart code will go here
var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
chart.dataProvider = chartData;
chart.categoryField = "country";

var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
graph.valueField = "visits";
graph.type = "column";
chart.addGraph(graph);

chart.write('chartdiv');
```

2) Or, use JSON based config with `AmCharts.makeChart()` function:

```
// chart code will go here
AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "categoryField": "country",
  "graphs": [ {
    "valueField": "visits",
    "type": "column"
  } ]
} );
```

Comment: Yes, seems like removing AmCharts.ready() worked fine! Thank you.